# What is the IDE of choice for Erlang development?

Tags: ide, erlang

I want to get into Erlang programming, specifically some [yaws](http://yaws.hyber.org/) stuff.  (Currently, I use Eclipse for Java development.)

What is the IDE of choice for Erlang development?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While there are several choices of plugins for NetBeans or Eclipse, the officially recommended IDE is [Erlang mode for Emacs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang_mode.html)

Comment: erlang-mode is being actively developed as "erlware-mode": http://code.google.com/p/erlware-mode/

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse does the job just fine for me with the Erlang plugin. If you are already familiar with that through Java development why not simply stick with that?

I have also used JEdit and it performs pretty well.

Both are pretty good at syntax highlighting and have templates for new modules (OTP etc.).

Although I agree that Emacs is the "official" editor of choice you don't have to use it (and learn a whole new editing approach) if you don't want to.

Comment: thanks.  i think i'll start with the plugin until i have my head around the basics, and then switch to emacs when i get to some unknown point.

Answer (score 5):

Emacs is the IDE of choice. It supports [Distel](http://fresh.homeunix.net/~luke/distel/) which plugs your editor into a cluster of Erlang Virtual Machines as an Erlang node in its own right (maaan!).

Answer (score 4):

If you are a new emacs user, I think emacs can really kill you :(

I try `erlide`(buggy for jump to defination, other is good) `emacs-erlang` mode(really hard for me), I finally choose `sublime text2` for daily development. I suggest you can try it.

i install the following plugins:

```
package control
sublime-erlang
sublimerl
ctags
```

that's as good as I expected.

Answer (score 3):

Look for this one:

IntelliJ IDEA + Erlang plugin
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7083-erlang/

Answer (score 2):

If you use Eclipse already, [Erlide](http://erlide.sourceforge.net/) works nicely. I do think that Emacs with [erlware-mode](http://code.google.com/p/erlware-mode/) is better, but the learning curve may be a bit steep.