# What's a good IDE for Erlang programming?

Tags: ide, erlang

As far as I know there's Erlang plugin for NetBeans and Eclipse. Which one has the upper hand at the moment?

Are there any other IDE for Erlang which I didnt mention, and how good are they when compare with NetBeans and Eclipse?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109084/what-is-the-ide-of-choice-for-erlang-development

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The best IDE for Erlang is Emacs. However, the mode which ships with Erlang isn't the best. [Erlware-mode](http://code.google.com/p/erlware-mode/) extends it and [Distel](http://code.google.com/p/distel/) allows you to use Emacs itself as an Erlang node, enabling some very nice features. See [this](http://bc.tech.coop/blog/070528.html) blog post.

Between plugins for NetBeans (ErlyBird) and Eclipse (ErlIDE), I prefer the Eclipse one. NetBeans at least used to require nightly versions of NetBeans and didn't work properly for me.

Comment: Beware that "the Erlware Emacs Mode is deprecated. All significant changes made to the Erlware version have been incorporated into the
latest release of the official distribution."

Comment: Yes. And all the links to erlware related projects are dead.

Answer (score 81):

[Erlang plugin](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?pluginId=7083) for IntelliJ IDEA provides some features for Erlang code editing and navigation:

- Syntax and errors highlighting
- References resolving
- Code completion for functions, records, variables, macroses and keywords
- Rename refactoring for modules, functions, records, macroses and variables
- Safe delete refactoring
- Structure view and Find usages
- Code formatter
- Compilation and running
- Eunit test runner
- Dialyzer integration
- Snippets (Live Templates)
- Quick-fixes
- Rebar integration
- Emacs-based code formatting action
- Erlang shell console
- Debugger
- Extract variable and function refactorings

The plugins is free and open sourced: http://ignatov.github.io/intellij-erlang.

Answer (score 13):

I use Erlide on eclipse (http://erlide.org/).

Pros:
Syntax highlight, autocompletion and suggestion all work well.
During suggest it will display some documentationif available: very useful when exploring a module.

Error and warning annotiations are quick and helpful.

All things considered the user experience is good, especially if you are used to eclipse.

Cons:
Erlide can also run your modules, but I find the shell is too clunky to be usable. I always keep a "real" erlang shell open and compile/test my code from there.

There is also a Textmate bundle (google), but I have not tried that yet.

Comment: Erlide 0.56.0 does not work with Erlang 25.0 as reported in the issue "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73920540/running-an-erlang-application-in-eclipse-is-throwing-an-exception"

Answer (score 11):

Erlang mode in Emacs is the generally recommended IDE.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/tools/erlang_mode_chapter.html

If you just want basic syntax highlighting in Windows I have written a syntax definition for NotePad++ that works well:

http://www.roberthorvick.com/2009/07/08/syntax-highlighing-for-erlang-in-notepad/

There is an Erlang definition for vim that I'm sure Google knows how to find.

I'm sure others have done the same for other editors.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Vim I recommend you **Vimerl** (http://github.com/jimenezrick/vimerl):

### Features

- Syntax highlighting
- Code indenting
- Code folding
- Code omni completion
- Syntax checking with quickfix support
- Code skeletons for the OTP behaviours
- Uses configuration from Rebar
- Pathogen compatible (http://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)

Comment: See this recent post on integrating vim & erlang: http://blog.erlware.org/2013/09/09/how-to-use-vim-for-erlang-development/

Answer (score 6):

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) has a great Erlang plugin

http://ignatov.github.io/intellij-erlang/

Answer (score 5):

I use SciTE: http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html as I cant be bothered to learn the emacs key combinations, and am to impatient to wait for eclipse to load.

SciTE comes with an Erlang configuration, but it needs to be uncommented in  the configuration file.

Comment: Forgot to mention that it is cross platform (A must for me)

Comment: Scite supports Windows and Linux, though.

Answer (score 5):

I used [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) and Vim,
they are good enough for developing.
Geany can also compile and run the code.

Answer (score 3):

I use notpad++ for erlang

Answer (score 3):

Another option is Visual Studio Code with the [erlang extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pgourlain.erlang).

Comment: Agree,  2020 now days， i recommand use vscode with erlang plugins to develop erlang.

Answer (score 1):

if you are a new emacs user, i think emacs can really kill you :(

i try erlide(buggy for jump to defination, other is good) emacs-erlang mode(really hard for me), i finally choose sublime text2 for daily development. i suggest you can try it.

i install the following plugins: package control sublime-erlang sublimerl ctags

that's as good as i expected.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T0rD0CQM4Yg

you can watch this video to see how friendly sublime 2 is

Answer (score 1):

I use Eclipse with Erlide plugin.

It has support for Project Management in addition to syntax highlight, autocompletion.

Integration with 3rd party tool such as Wrangler for code refactoring is also very useful.

Debugging is also supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sublime text on windows, mac and linux

Answer (score -1):

Emacs or VIM is not a good choice, if you didn't have experience on them.
There a too many bugs in Eclipse...
And IntelliJ IDEA is the best IDE