# Running an Erlang Application in Eclipse is throwing an exception

Tags: eclipse, erlang, erlide

I have installed Erlang OTP 25.0, erlide 0.56.0, Eclipse 2022-09 & Java 18. I have created a new Erlang project and module. I am facing 2 issues.

Issue #1:
Getting an error when I tried to launch the Eclipse after creating the Erlang project.

Issue #2:
When I tried to run the application, I am getting an exception "Launching App1 has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during launching App1. Expected the service OtpNodeProxy 5756dc@null FAILED to be running, but the service has FAILED" as shown in the screenshot ErlangRunConfigException. Please help me in resolving the issue.

I have followed the procedure given below.

1. Installed Eclipse and Erlide plugin
2. Installed Erlang OTP 25.0 from https://www.erlang.org/patches/otp-25.0
3. Updated the environment PATH to refer to the Erlang installation path. I cross-checked this setting by typing "werl".
4. In Eclipse, Erlang InstalledRuntimes is automatically updated with the Erlang version 25.0. Refer to the screenshot ErlangInstalledRuntime
5. Created a Erlang project and module.
6. Edited the Hello.erl with HelloWorld code.
7. In Eclipse->RunConfguration, created an ErlangApplication (refer to the screenshot RunConfig-ErlangApp-Erlang). I set RunTime and Node name as shown in the screenshot RunConfig-ErlangApp-Runtime. Selected the Windows PATH as shown in the screenshot RunConfig-ErlangApp-Environment.

**Hello.erl**

````
```
-module(hello).
-export([hello_world/0]).
hello_world() -> io:fwrite("hello, world\n").
```
````

**Images:**
ErlangRunConfigException.png
[image: Erlang RunConfig Exception]

ErlangInstalledRuntime.png
[image: Erlang Installed Runtime Setting]

RunConfig-ErlangApp-Environment.png
[image: RunConfig-ErlangApp-Environment]

RunConfig-ErlangApp-Runtime.png
[image: RunConfig-ErlangApp-Runtime]

werl output
[image: werl output]

RunConfig-ErlangApp-Erlang.png
[image: RunConfig-ErlangApp-Erlang]

Project structure
[image: Project Structure]

Eclipse Launching Error
[image: Eclipse Launching Error]

Comment: I have renamed the Hello.erl as hello.erl to match the module name. But the issue persists.

Comment: I have changed the node name to erlide instead of the autogenerated name 5756dc (refer to RunConfig-ErlangApp-Runtime.png). But the issue persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Erlang 25 doesn't load beam files older than v21, and the files included in erlide are that old. I am not really maintaining the project anymore, I can try to rebuild with v25, but can make no promises. Even then, the debugger will no longer work, it can be good to note.

Comment: Thank you Vlad. I am using Erlide 0.56.0. Until you rebuild Erlide with an appropriate version of beam files, do you suggest any workaround? Say using an older version of Erlang or Erlide?

Comment: It should work with any older versions, maybe with the exception of the debugger. I don't know when I will be able to rebuild erlide, I lost the development environment and I don't work with Erlang anymore...

Comment: Thanks Vlad for responding. I tried 24.3, 24.0, and 23.0. No luck. The issue persists. Do you suggest me to check with a much older version of Erlang?

Answer (score 0):

The reported issue is seen with the latest Erlang version 25.0 and the older versions I have checked till 23.0. As a workaround, I have migrated to IntelliJ IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use Erlang version 25.3 along with Eclipse with Erlide by following the instruction from the below:
https://erlide.org/articles/eclipse/120_Installing-and-updating.html

One important note is the first instruction
*Install a supported Erlang version like Erlang/OTP 23, if it isn’t already present on your system. **On Windows systems, use a path with no spaces in it**.*

Looks like the path should not have spaces in it. I faced the issue listed above when I had spaces. Once I reinstalled by removing the spaces in the path. it started to work.

**Works:** C:\Program Files\ErlangOTP

**Does NOT work**: C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, here. In your "works" path, there is still a space between "Program" and "Files".